# How to return all project employees?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have datas of following format collection(projects) inside my database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5981a80f223e491a58230e5d"), "id" : 2, "name" : "gbqplhlqxzwl", "managerId" : 65151, "startDate" : "03.11.1999", "finishDate" : "02.01.2003", "projectStatus" : "POSTPONED", "participants" : [ ], "estimatedBudget" : 6017891.811079914 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5981a80f223e491a58230e5e"), "id" : 3, "name" : "erfekfsdgryu", "managerId" : 83749, "startDate" : "07.07.2007", "finishDate" : "26.12.2027", "projectStatus" : "POSTPONED", "participants" : [ 19229, 81856, 79270, 5509, 70344, 39424 ], "estimatedBudget" : 3086213.8981674756 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5981a80f223e491a58230e5f"), "id" : 1, "name" : "jvbzobhppntd", "managerId" : 18925, "startDate" : "29.04.1999", "finishDate" : "13.10.2008", "projectStatus" : "OPEN", "participants" : [ 46100, 96968, 6676, 56121, 4716, 68901, 43990, 48587, 62547, 30292, 65153, 17551, 27083, 20261, 27097, 50036, 86585, 69890, 18790, 22592, 60774, 93709, 78471, 27157, 4328, 36501, 47296, 16831 ], "estimatedBudget" : 3581496.7068344904 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5981a80f223e491a58230e60"), "id" : 4, "name" : "cdspkkqwvwld", "managerId" : 62042, "startDate" : "13.03.1998", "finishDate" : "20.06.2007", "projectStatus" : "OPEN", "participants" : [ 53480, 60897, 23677, 22064, 60807, 66637, 84609, 28378, 87143, 27675, 79283, 94992, 20429, 48769, 91671, 41747, 21651, 91134, 41684, 57228, 51949, 18756, 45679, 87781, 67287, 6902, 27526 ], "estimatedBudget" : 2126283.953787842 }
....
```

I need to find the busiest employee and list all his projects.

`participants` array contains employee ids who participate in the project.

I use the  following query to find the busiest employee:

```
db.projects.aggregate(
    {
        $unwind: '$participants'
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            count: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : '$participants',
            participation_count : {
                '$sum':'$count'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{participation_count:-1}
    },
    {
        $limit:1
    }
)
```

and this work correctly. But I have no ideas how to list all his projects.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.projects.aggregate(
    [
    {
        $unwind: '$participants'
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            count: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : '$participants',
            participation_count : {'$sum':'$count'},
            projectId : {$push: '$id'}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{participation_count:-1}
    },
    {
        $limit:1
    }
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse:true
    }
)
```